# Stronger bound on abelianization of 2-transitive group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, finite-groups

Theorem 1 of [On abelian quotients of primitive groups](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1989-107-01/S0002-9939-1989-0982398-4/) states that
$$
|G/G'| \leq n 
$$
for any primitive permutation group $ G $ of degree $ n $. In other words, for primitive permutation groups the size of the abelianization is bounded by the degree.

Is it the case that
$$
|G/G'|\leq n-1
$$
for any 2-transitive permutation group $ G $ of degree $ n $?

That slightly stronger bound seems to hold for the 2-transitive group AGL(1,n) of degree $ n $.

Side note: It's interesting to note that the bound $ n $ fails for transitive groups. For example consider the degree $ n=128 $ group $ 2 \wr 2^6 $, where $ 2^6 $ is an elementary abelian $ 2 $ group. This group has abelianization of size bounded below by $ 2^9 $ (see equation 6.2 of the reference above) and so is certainly not bounded above by the degree $ 2^7 $.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin No

Comment: Apart from the silly exception $S_2$, the statement holds for groups of affine type by the main theorem of https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11425-018-9460-2

Comment: Since the "other" 2-transitive groups are almost simple, this is very likely to hold in general.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin As Brauer Suzuki pointed out, $ S_3 $ has abelianization of size $ 2=S_3/A_3 $, not $ 3 $. Perhaps the counter example you meant to bring up is that $ S_2 $ is a 2-transitive group of degree 2 with abelianization of size 2?

Comment: silly mistake, yes.

Comment: Kovacs and Newman in 1988 constructed examples of transitive groups $G$ of degree $n$ (for $n$ a power of $2$) with $|G/G'| = 2^{O(n/\log(n))}$.